# In Kotlin how do I create a button in a fragment that open an activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin how do I create a button in a fragment that opens an activity and it's corresponding kt file?

I have tried everything from similar questions in here.

Comment: if you want some help show your code

Comment: post the code you have tried and any related error messages or logs

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your attempts, and to explain exactly how they're not working.

Comment: Post your code .

Comment: What exactly you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways:

1) Inside the fragment itself:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
        requireActivity().startActivity(
            Intent(requireActivity(), SecondActivity::class.java)
        )
    }
```

Where by `requireActivity()` you are basically telling your fragment to use the parent activity as an activity/context and start an Intent from there.

2) Using callback to the activity. 
Define the next Interface:

```
interface FragmentCallback {
     fun startNextActivity()
}
```

Instantiate your interface in the fragment as a nullable object:

```
 private var fragmentCallback: FragmentCallback? = null
```

Make sure you tell your fragment about the interface in onAttatch() override method:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    try {
        if (context is FragmentCallback)
            fragmentCallback = context
    } catch (e: Exception) {}
}
```

Implement your button functionality:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
          fragmentCallback.startNextActivity()
    }
```

Then in your main activity implement the interface:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FragmentCallback
```

Your activity will require the override method of your interface. Implement the method:

```
override fun startNextActivity() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
}
```

As you can see the old fashion way interface implementation takes a lot of useless lines of code. Using the `requireActivity()` method is the easiest and fastest.